# How to write a crontab script, that will check a process' status and launch it if not running?

Tags: cron, process-management

qBittorrent-nox which was running perfectly until last week, but since then it always crashes on my Ubuntu 14.04. Theoretically it's logging, but the log file only conatines these lines:

```
******** Információ ********
A qBittorrent vezérléséhez, nyisd meg ezt a címet: localhost:8080
Web UI adminisztrátor felhasználó neve: admin
Web UI adminisztrátor jelszó még az alapértelmezett: adminadmin
Ez biztonsági kockázatot jelent. Kérlek változtass jelszót a program beállításinál.
******** Információ ********
A qBittorrent vezérléséhez, nyisd meg ezt a címet: localhost:8080
Web UI adminisztrátor felhasználó neve: weylyn1
******** Információ ********
A qBittorrent vezérléséhez, nyisd meg ezt a címet: localhost:8080
Web UI adminisztrátor felhasználó neve: weylyn1
******** Információ ********
A qBittorrent vezérléséhez, nyisd meg ezt a címet: localhost:8080
Web UI adminisztrátor felhasználó neve: weylyn1
```

. So i would like to write a script, that will check in every 5 minute, whether qbittorrent-nox is running or not and if it's not running, then start it with `# service qbittorrent-nox start` (as root). However if it's running, then wait for 5 more minutes and check it again. I would like to use this workaround, until a solution is found for the crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to test if a daemon is running? It depends. Some daemons has a file with the process ID in say `/var/run/foo.pid`. An example of that is `/var/run/crond.pid`.

```
$ cat /var/run/crond.pid
432
```

If the process is running it has a directory in `/proc`:

```
$ ls /proc/$(cat /var/run/crond.pid)
```

So if the directory in /proc does not exists we can do a restart. If qBittorrent has this pid-file you can do this:

```
# cat <<EOF >/etc/cron.d/restart-qbittorrent-nox
*/5 * * * * /bin/test -e /proc/$(cat /var/run/qbittorrent-nox.pid)/cmdline || service qbittorrent-nox start
EOF
```

If you don't have any file in `/var/run` you have to use `ps ax | grep qBittorrent` to find the process.

But the best solution would be to find out why the process crashes...

Comment: Thanks! I've already written to the developers about this issue (because it's log file doesn't have anything that could point me to right direction about the crash), and now I'm waiting for reply.

Comment: I had to modify the script a bit, because i have no process called qBittorrent. It is called qbittorrent-nox (and it's pid file is called qbittorrent-nox.pid).

Comment: I have changed my answer to fit your respond. If this exactly works I would delete my comments.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. qbittorrent-nox hasn't been started after it crashed, no matter how much time did i wait. Now i use Ubuntu 16.04 and with a workaround (installed from another, unofficial repository), it seems to be working.